# how to write fit function for special equation?

Tags: matlab

i'm going to fit an special equation in matlab using `fit` function.
the equation is :

[image]

and my code is :

```
myfittype = fittype('(exp(L*H*(1/T-1/520))-1)/L',...
'dependent',{'x'},'independent',{'T'},...
'coefficients',{'L','H'});

opt = fitoptions(myfittype);
opt.StartPoint = [1 1];


[FitObj gof] = fit(T',x',myfittype,opt)
```

and my result is :

```
gof = 

       sse: 2.2019e+07
   rsquare: 0.7551
       dfe: 6
adjrsquare: 0.7143
      rmse: 1.9157e+03
```

, plot result is like this :

[image]
as u see rsquare is not close to 1 , which means it's not a good fit.
what should i do to make it better ?

Comment: 0.7551 is not terrible, although R^2 is fairly meaningless unless you're doing linear regression. I don't see any reason why `fit` would do a good job. Have you plotted your data against your fit?

Comment: plot of result has added , note that i had real result from an article which says rsquare can reach to 0.978 . but my best rsquare is .7551,

Comment: would u check my equation wrote in matlab ? did equation write in a right way?

Comment: You are fitting `(1-x)/x` as a function of `T` not `x` as a function of `T`, you need to finish rearranging the equation so it is `x=...` not `(1-x)/x=...`.

Comment: could u say what should i do exactly ?

Comment: actually `x` means `x = (1-solubility)./solubility` and `solubilty` is `x1`

Comment: You've rearranged your function to get `(exp(L*H*(1/T-1/520))-1)/L`, but if you look at the original equation you'll see that this should be equal to `(1-x)/x`, but you want to fit `x=x(T)`, so you need to write your function so it equal to `x`.